# How to pass string parameter through onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm generating a table through ajax function. But I need to add onclick function.Inside this function passing two parameters one is number and other is name.

**Controller**

```
 $table.='  <td><input type="checkbox"  value="" id="sp_'.$app_id.'" onclick="SpDetails('.$app_id.','.$app_details->app_name.');" /></td>'

 echo  $table;
```

**script**

```
 function SpDetails(val,name)
 {
    alert(name)

 }
```

But I didn't get the name when I alert.

Comment: any errors you see?

Comment: No errors ..onclick is not working whe i pass the parameter as name.otherwise okey

Comment: right click and inspect button to see what php print.
note: you have extra double quotes `here id="sp_'.$app_id.'" "`

Comment: here shows the particular name without quotes like (1,alnin bnou sohu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You have extra `"` here `id="sp_'.$app_id.'" "`.
- Pass the second parameter as string so you miss double quotes.
- Internal double quotes should be escaped like this `"foo \" foo"`.
- You can pass variable in strings with double quotes `"$variable"`.

so your code should be like this

```
   $table.="  <td><input type='checkbox'  value='' id='sp_$a' onclick='SpDetails($a,\"$b\");' /></td>";


     echo $table;
```

Comment: i removed.i got the name inside the quotes when in inspect but the onclick function is not working

Comment: any quotes in script..?

Comment: try updated. quotes should be escaped by back slashes ` \ `.

Comment: `'i'm'` ==> `'i\'m'` also `"douple " qoute"` ==> `"douple \" qoute"`. and in your example you can pass $variable directly inside `"$variable"`.

Answer (score 2):

your parameter has no quote so it throws error . Use `\'` for making parameter as a string .

```
$table ='<td><input type="checkbox"  value="" id="sp_'.$app_id.'" onclick="SpDetails(\''.$app_id.'\',\''.$app_details->app_name.'\');" /></td>';
```

That will write in html as

```
<input onclick="SpDetails('app_id','app_name');"> //that is just example
```

Your orginal is

```
<input onclick="SpDetails(app_id,app_name);">  //no quote so assume as variable
```

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
 onclick="SpDetails('" .$app_id. "','" .$app_details->app_name. "');"
```

Comment: how can we use '+' its purely php